# Login bug in email address

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, login, user-accounts, email

I have two valid email addresses in my account.  As of 5-9 hours ago, I tried to log into one of the SE sites (superuser), and couldn't get in.  Long story short, I reset my password and still couldn't log in.  I've now verified that I am able to log in with one of my two email addresses, but not the other, in spite of the fact that the password reset email told me I could use either.  I verified this by copy-pasting the password and email address just to be extra-safe.  In case it helps, the email address that worked was an old email address that I signed up for SE with, the other (that doesn't work) is the new email I actively use.  The latter is the email address listed in my preferences on SE.

**UPDATE**
I've verified this behavior on 3 computers (Windows 10 and 7) and 2 browsers (Chrome and Edge).

**UPDATE 2**
Here's the password reset email, with my email/name redacted.
[image]

Comment: You can't have two username/email accounts (previously known as Stack Exchange OpenID) as far as I know. You can only have one of those, plus one external provider like Google, Yahoo, etc. Maybe it did work somehow while SE was OpenID provider but now that it is not, good chance it stopped supporting such  cases.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Well, the email says I can.  Further, the email address that didn't work is the one that's listed in my user account.  I'm ~87% confident that I've logged in with that email address in the past.

Comment: @ShadowWizard That's not true anymore, and hasn't been for a very long time. You can have an infinite number of credentials and there's no limit to how many of a particular type. You might be thinking of the old way (primary and alternate credentials).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your new email address is not yet set up as a credential and you cannot use it to login. The only thing you ever did with it was enter it into your Email Settings page and verified it, so that it could be used for all of your email notifications. That process alone does not allow it to be used for login.

If you want to set it up as a credential too, you'll need to visit the My Logins section while editing your profile and click the "add more logins" button, then complete the process by entering the email and a password to be associated with it. Once that process is complete, you'll be able to login using both email addresses.

As a hint, you can always visit the My Logins page to view your available credentials. If your email address is listed under the "Other" section then it is *not* set up as a credential and cannot be used for login. It needs to be listed under the "Stack Exchange" section at the top of the list.

Comment: Hmm, if I go to My Logins, it lists my new email address and says I have used it (to log in, I presume), but there's no button to change the password.

Comment: @TTT As I state at the bottom of my answer, if it's listed as Other then it is not usable as a credential. That means it's only attached to your account as a verified email, and the used date will simply be the date you attached it.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't understand those to be one and the same; could you add that last bit about what the date implies to your answer?